# mongodb can $unionWith use in $push

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to get related data based on current item processing.

Sample:

```
[
    { field1: 1, field2: 2, value: 12 },
    { field1: 1, field2: 2, value: 21 },
    { field1: 1, value: 1 },
    { field2: 2, value: 2 },
    { field1: 2, field2: 3, value: 23 }

];
```

and result:

```
[
    {
        _id: { field1: 1, field2: 2 },
        value: [12, 12],
        relatedValue: [1, 2], // of item 1 and 2 because field 1 = 1 or field 2 = 2
    },
];
```

Sample query:

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { field1: 1 }
  },
  {
    "$group":{
      "_id":{
        "field1":"$field1",
        "field2":"$field2"
      },
      "alerts":{
        "$push":{
          "_id":"$_id",
          "value":"$value",
          "relatedData": {
            "$unionWith": {
               "coll": "collectionA",
               "pipeline": [{
                 "$match": {
                   "$or": [
                     { "field1": "$field1" },
                     { "field2": "$field2" }
                   ]
                 }
               }]   
             }     
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I tried run this query but error, Please help me fix or give a solution

// Edited: value should be array because I want to group data by field1, field2 and push all value of group to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) within `$group` but it is a "pipeline stage" meaning it can't be used like that, the same way you can't use `$group` within a `$group`.

Additionally this stage is used to "union" two collections and not to populate data based on value matches ( which it seems you're trying to do here ), for this case you want to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        field1: "$field1",
        field2: "$field2",
        docId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $or: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$field1",
                        "$field1"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$field2",
                        "$field2"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$docId",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            value: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "relatedData"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        field1: "$field1",
        field2: "$field2"
      },
      values: {
        $push: "$value"
      },
      relatedValue: {
        $push: {
          $map: {
            input: "$relatedData",
            in: "$$this.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      field1: "$_id.field1",
      field2: "$_id.field2",
      values: 1,
      relatedValues: {
        "$setDifference": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              input: "$relatedValue",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                "$setUnion": [
                  "$$this",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "$values"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RkNdOo4I1fz)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake that value is number, it should be an array, that why I used $group. Please take a look sample again. And I want to add a $match stage to first stage as well to filter data before

Comment: like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/FUfy5ojLLJD

Comment: yes but it's not group, https://mongoplayground.net/p/_lvwkC2o_oU please check it.  Object [0] and [4] should be merged to 1 object. Like: {
    "_id": {
      "field1": 1,
      "field2": 2
    },
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2,
    "relatedValues": [
      1,
      2
    ],
    "values": [
      12,
      21
    ]

Comment: I found the issue, https://mongoplayground.net/p/RkNdOo4I1fz.

honestly now knowing you intended to `$group`, i would `$group` first then do the `$lookup`. that would save the issue we just had and the need to use `$setDifference`.

Comment: Can I add merge values and relatedData become an array, values = [1,2,12,21]? and can I add a stage to filter data at first stage ? I just want to get object have both field field1, field2. And result of aggregate just [
  {
    "_id": {
      "field1": 1,
      "field2": 2
    },
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2,
    "relatedValues": [
      1,
      2,
      12,
      21
    ],
    "values": [
      1,
      2,
      12,
      21
    ]
  }, {
  _id: { field1: 2, field2: 3 },
values: [23]
}
]

Comment: sure, just use `$concatArrays` or `$setUnion` depending on the behavior you want.

Comment: how about add $match to get only the record have both fields, but value still includes all record have field1 = $field1 or field2 = $field1

Comment: You can obviously add it if that's what you need, I just gave the answer that works generically for all documents in the collection and satisfies the output required structure.

if you need to make any custom changes to make it work for your usecase then by all means go for it.